# How do I sum items fulfilled split into columns by transaction month?

Tags: sql, t-sql, odbc, netsuite

I'm trying to sum up the item sales split into each month using an ODBC connection to my Netsuite database. I'm running the query using Microsoft Excel's database connection, so I *think* it's using T-SQL standards, at least judging from what I've tried.

I wrote this query to give me a list of items from item fulfillment transactions. Line-items that have the actual `item_id` are stored in the `TRANSACTION_LINES` table, and the transaction type is in the `TRANSACTIONS` table, thus the join.

```
SELECT trandate
    ,item_id
    ,item_count
FROM Administrator.TRANSACTIONS
    ,Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES
WHERE Administrator.TRANSACTIONS.transaction_id = Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES.transaction_id
    AND trandate >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 6), 'month')
    AND transaction_type = 'Item Fulfillment'
```

This gave me a table like so:

```
trandate        item_id     item_count
2/3/2016 0:00   13035       -2
2/3/2016 0:00   13035       2
2/3/2016 0:00   13035       -2
2/3/2016 0:00   2809        -2
2/3/2016 0:00   2809        2
2/3/2016 0:00   2809        -2
2/3/2016 0:00   13049       -2
2/3/2016 0:00   13049       2
2/3/2016 0:00   13049       -2
2/3/2016 0:00   13111       -2
2/3/2016 0:00   13111       2
2/3/2016 0:00   13111       -2
2/2/2016 0:00   13103       -1
2/2/2016 0:00   13103       1
2/2/2016 0:00   13103       -1
2/2/2016 0:00   195712      -2
2/1/2016 0:00   213120      -2
2/1/2016 0:00   213120      2
2/1/2016 0:00   213120      -2
2/1/2016 0:00   213122      -2
2/1/2016 0:00   213122      2
2/1/2016 0:00   213122      -2
```

You can imagine this going on for a while, for everything going back until august. I think alternating negatives are something Netsuite does for the stock impact on different accounts, although if someone wants to provide more insight for that as well I'd be thankful

So now I try to pivot this query using a `case when` and aggregate sum. I'm only going to put the column for the first month, since the following months are the same, with the `-1` changed correspondingly. I also negate the quantity so the sum total will be positive.

```
SELECT A.item_id
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN A.trandate BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 1), 'month')
                    AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 1))
                THEN - 1 * A.item_count
            ELSE 0
            END) as OneMonthSales
FROM (--the query we defined earlier, now as a subquery
    SELECT trandate
        ,item_id
        ,item_count
    FROM Administrator.TRANSACTIONS
        ,Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES
    WHERE Administrator.TRANSACTIONS.transaction_id = Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES.transaction_id
        AND trandate >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 6), 'month')
        AND transaction_type = 'Item Fulfillment'
    ) AS A
group by A.item_id
```

Excel doesn't want to execute this query.
[image: excel refuses to execute query]

If I remove the `A.` prefix from `group by A.item_id`, i get the same error.
If I comment out the `group by` clause, the query will execute and return a table with the item_id and one column for one-month sales, but the item_id rows are still repeated (even more times, it seems). This seems extra-strange to me, since I thought every column not in an aggregate function needs to be in a `group by` clause, otherwise it should throw an error.

How can I fix this query so it will pivot properly and sum the quantity for each item_id? If I can get it to work for one month, I can probably extend it as far as I need.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your query in a stored procedure and running the sp from the excel! Just an idea.

Comment: @KamranFarzami I don't think Netsuite (as a proprietary system) allows for a stored procedure, unless I'm misunderstanding. Just getting an ODBC connection requires purchasing an additional module from them - typically all queries are done from a very limited search interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the query in another select statement like so:

```
--get sales data
SELECT item_id, sum(OneMonthSales)
FROM (
    SELECT item_id
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN A.trandate BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 1), 'month')
                        AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 1))
                    THEN - 1 * A.item_count
                ELSE 0
                END) as OneMonthSales
    FROM (
        SELECT trandate
            ,item_id
            ,item_count
        FROM Administrator.TRANSACTIONS
            ,Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES
        WHERE Administrator.TRANSACTIONS.transaction_id = Administrator.TRANSACTION_LINES.transaction_id
            AND trandate >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GETDATE(), - 6), 'month')
            AND transaction_type = 'Item Fulfillment'
        ) AS A
)
group by item_id
```

This does what I expect, but if someone can provide an answer that does it without this, or an answer with this explaining why it is necessary, I will accept that answer.